# Can I take a laptop, an iPad and a phone on flight from Europe the JFK?

Tags: usa, air-travel, hand-luggage, jfk

I have flight from Oslo to New York, can I take a laptop, iPad (with Apple pencil) and my personal phone in hand luggage?

I remember reading some news that now international flights to the US don't allow electronic devices with batteries. Is that true?

Comment: Yes you can. I have done this 100s of time including last week :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible, all the people who are carrying phones, laptops..., that would be impossible to ban all electronics with batteries, full stop, I don't know where you got that news from

Usually, the rule is that you aren't allowed to carry electronics that can't turn on
(i.e. without a battery or with an empty battery) because CBP can elect to search it or more easily check that the laptop is actually a laptop and not a hideout for illegal substances

From this [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/35818/118049)

> The whole idea behind making sure that electronic devices work is to make sure that the internal parts are not replaced with a bomb, if someone tries to smuggle a bomb inside an electronic device, it will not be possible to achieve that while keeping the original components intact, so the best is just to make sure the device is working and this will exclude any possibility of hiding bomb parts inside electronic devices (laptops, tablets, etc.). It is simple yet effective method.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, I found this link now: https://www.nytimes.com/2017/07/20/business/laptop-ban-air-travel.html

Comment: @krishna Yeah, laptop ban was a thing, but it is long gone

Comment: There have been restrictions on carrying electronics with large lithium batteries in **checked** (hold) baggage, which airlines will tell you about in their detailed rules. But the question asks about hand baggage, which doesn't have the same issue (it is easier to handle a fire in cabin baggage, and people carry fewer items in hand baggage).