# Can I take my gaming computer as luggage? Leaving Saudi Arabia to Malaysia in 27hours

Tags: luggage, electronic-items, malaysia, saudi-arabia, malaysia-airlines

So basically, I have this [small form factor](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/DKN2OIYYvFs/hqdefault.jpg) gaming PC that I built a [few months back](https://www.reddit.com/r/buildapc/comments/3rnzr2/build_readygive_my_skylake_mitx_rvz02b_build_a/?ref=share&ref_source=link) for portability*, and I will be leaving to Malaysia to study*, but I believe I might need a capable PC since my laptop mostly isn't, I would put the whole PC inside my main luggage with my clothes, but I fear that as a Saudi young man, they might have me interrogated (because ISIS 'n all that BS) and waste my time at the airport*,

So what do I do to make sure to bring it with me? 
Can I dissemble it and will it then pass through without question?
Do I *really* have to give it to someone to ship it to me?

and an another sub-question, if I had removed and taken the PCs hard drives instead, will I be required to show the airport its contents? I mainly have a lot of animated movies downloaded and large-sized games.

Notes*: -Malaysia Airlines -Total weight is less than 30KG -I am an art student who does 3D for hobby

Comment: See also: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3748/flying-with-a-desktop-computer-as-checked-luggage

Comment: And http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/59110/diy-computer-in-hand-luggage-what-to-expect-on-security-checks?rq=1 - for some more advice on taking it in hand luggage.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest taking it in your hand luggage (if it'll fit in the dimensions).

My main concern about putting a PC into your checked luggage would be a) it getting broken, or b) it getting stolen. The airline's liability for lost or stolen luggage is relatively low - perhaps below the cost of your PC. Even if it's not, then you do face the hassle of replacement - and of convincing them that the damage to your fragile item was their fault.

I have, however, taken a small form factor PC in *hand luggage* before (on Malaysia Airlines as it happens, in 2015). It was in a dodgy looking black holdall and no-one batted an eyelid, either in London or when I changed planes and recleared security in Kuala Lumpur.

In case they asked me to switch it on (they didn't), I brought a power lead, and I think a couple of bits like a keyboard. I arrived 3 hours early just in case they wouldn't let it go in hand luggage and forced me to check it in. The thumbscrews on the case would have allowed me to open it up if need be - don't bring a screwdriver!

Unfortunately my experience is only anecdotal. But at least it's one data point for you.

And with regard to the hard drives - no-one at airport security is likely to care what's on the hard drives. Malaysian customs could theoretically care - you're not allowed to bring in anything pornographic or seditious, but then you're probably not allowed that in Saudi Arabia either.